# Jquery count only numbers in a string

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

My question is: How I can count only numbers from a string, for example if I have:
(55)-555-34 to get output 7, I mean to exclude the dashes and brackets for example. Cheers!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use [.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with `/\d/g`  *Regular Expression*:

```
"(55)-555-34".match(/\d/g).length
//result=>7
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove all non-numbers with [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), and get the length of the result string:

```
str.replace(/\D/g,"").length
```

This has the advantage over applying [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) that you don't need to check for `null` results (in case no match is found).